# How can I pause video once another slide is chosen (Slick.js and VideoJS)

Tags: javascript, html, slick.js

I'm trying to make a video player along with carousel, when you click on individual carousel slide, required video opens and plays. However, my issue is that once the video is playing and you move on to the next slide the video remains to be playing. 
I tried to use this solution [Slick slider pause youtube video when slide change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349155/slick-slider-pause-youtube-video-when-slide-change) and although it does make it work, once the video stops, and then you come back to the same video that was paused, you can't play it again or interact with it at all, how can I fix that?.

HTML

```
<div class='col videoCarouselMain'>
      <div class='videoCarouselMainItem'>
        <video id='storyVideo' class='video-js vjs-default-skin' controls width='700px' height='600px' data-setup='{}'>
          <source src='./assets/video.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
        </video>
      </div>
      <div class='videoCarouselMainItem'>
        <video id='storyVideo' class='video-js vjs-default-skin' controls width='700px' height='600px' data-setup='{}'>
          <source src='./assets/video2.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
        </video>
      </div>
      <div class='videoCarouselMainItem'>
        <video id='storyVideo' class='video-js vjs-default-skin' controls width='700px' height='600px' data-setup='{}'>
          <source src='./assets/video.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
        </video>
      </div>
      <div class='videoCarouselMainItem'>
        <video id='storyVideo' class='video-js vjs-default-skin' controls width='700px' height='600px' data-setup='{}'>
          <source src='./assets/video.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class='col videoCarousel'>
      <div class='videoCarouselItem'>
        <img class='fluid' src='assets/videoPoster.jpg'>
      </div>
      <div class='videoCarouselItem'>
        <img class='fluid' src='assets/poster2.jpg'>
      </div>
      <div class='videoCarouselItem'>
        <img class='fluid' src='assets/videoPoster.jpg'>
      </div>
      <div class='videoCarouselItem'>
        <img class='fluid' src='assets/videoPoster.jpg'>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
$('.videoCarouselMain').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.videoCarousel'
});
$('.videoCarousel').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.videoCarouselMain',
  dots: true,
  centerMode: true,
  focusOnSelect: true
});


$('.videoCarouselMain').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  var current = $(slick.$slides[currentSlide]);
  current.html(current.html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Correct script.

```
.on(
  "beforeChange",
  function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    $(".slick-current video").attr(
      "src",
      $(".slick-current video").attr("src")
    );
    $(".slick-current .video-js").removeClass("vjs-playing");
  }
);
```